# OAuth signature with RSA-SHA1 on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cryptography, rsa

I need help creating an RSA-SHA1 signature to be used in a 3-legged OAuth implementation on iOS.

I was able to do this using HMAC-SHA1 using CommonCrypto.h, but this library doesn't seem to support RSA-SHA1.

Have any of you implemented OAuth signatures with RSA? Could you point me to some resources where I can find more information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The answer by Erik Villegas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17332182/1446005) was also the solution for me. But there is a bug in the posted code which I encountered  when using this solution: `secretFile` was opened with `fopen()`, so it must be closed with `fclose()`

```
- (NSString *)RSASHA1HashForString:(NSString *)source {

    NSLog(@"encrypting %@", source);

    if (source == nil) return nil;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    NSString *signature = nil;

    // make a SHA-1 digest of the source string
    const char* sourceChars = [source UTF8String];

    unsigned char digest[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    SHA1((const unsigned char *)sourceChars, strlen(sourceChars), digest);

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"privatekey" ofType:@"pem"];

    const char *pathCString = [path cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    FILE *secretFile = fopen(pathCString, "r");

    RSA *rsa = NULL;
    PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(secretFile, &rsa, NULL, NULL);


    if (rsa != NULL) {

        unsigned int sigLen = 0;
        unsigned char *sigBuff = malloc(RSA_size(rsa));

        int result = RSA_sign(NID_sha1, digest, (unsigned int) sizeof(digest),
                              sigBuff, &sigLen, rsa);

        if (result != 0) {
            NSData *sigData = [NSData dataWithBytes:sigBuff length:sigLen];
            signature = [self base64forData:sigData];
        }

        free(sigBuff);

        RSA_free(rsa);
    }

    fclose(secretFile);

    NSLog(@"generated signature: %@", signature);

    return signature;
}
```

Comment: I tried approving your edit (http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4797967), but it was rejected outright, seemingly being from an user with no rep; alas you cannot even comment on the post unless you have enough reputation.

Comment: That's right. Thank you. My edit was rejected and I was not able to comment, so I created this answer.

Comment: And I checked that you are right, the file indeed stays opened on my linux box after the PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey (there are some quite scary code in openssl anw), I was thinking to post into meta.stackoverflow about this.

Comment: Nice catch, I've switched your post to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

I finally found the solution. Here is a method that will look for a privatekey.pem file in your bundle and create a RSA-SHA1 signature using the string that is passed in. You will need to add the openssl library. You can use this project as a reference: https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone

```
- (NSString *)RSASHA1HashForString:(NSString *)source {

    NSLog(@"encrypting %@", source);

    if (source == nil) return nil;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    NSString *signature = nil;

    // make a SHA-1 digest of the source string
    const char* sourceChars = [source UTF8String];

    unsigned char digest[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    SHA1((const unsigned char *)sourceChars, strlen(sourceChars), digest);

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"privatekey" ofType:@"pem"];

    const char *pathCString = [path cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    FILE *secretFile = fopen(pathCString, "r");

    RSA *rsa = NULL;
    PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(secretFile, &rsa, NULL, NULL);


    if (rsa != NULL) {

        unsigned int sigLen = 0;
        unsigned char *sigBuff = malloc(RSA_size(rsa));

        int result = RSA_sign(NID_sha1, digest, (unsigned int) sizeof(digest),
                              sigBuff, &sigLen, rsa);

        if (result != 0) {
            NSData *sigData = [NSData dataWithBytes:sigBuff length:sigLen];
            signature = [self base64forData:sigData];
        }

        free(sigBuff);

        RSA_free(rsa);
    }

    NSLog(@"generated signature: %@", signature);

    return signature;
}
```

If you are implementing OAuth you'll need to pass the signature base into this method. More info can be found here: http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#anchor13

Comment: Hi Erik. I'm looking to do the same thing except I'm trying to connect to xero on osx. Are you able to expand on your solution for how to make calls to the xero api? Do you have any suggestions for openssl in OSX?

Comment: I was also trying to connect to Xero when I ran into this problem. [This Xero documentation](http://developer.xero.com/documentation/getting-started/public-applications) was my main resource. It is strictly OAuth 1.0, so the [OAuth documentation](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a) also helped a lot in how to construct the requests. I'm not sure how to get openSSL working on OS X. You'll probably have to download [the source code](http://www.openssl.org/source/), compile it, and include the static library in your application. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Erik. I will see if I can compile openssl from source. Did you use a library for the OAuth part? If so, what did you use?

Comment: I used [cocoa-oauth](https://github.com/guicocoa/cocoa-oauth). Of course I had to modify it to use RSA instead of the default HMAC-SHA1. The modified version I made for Xero can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/erikvillegas/8143166)

Comment: Erik.. you are a legend! It works!! I've been trying to get this to work for ages. Thanks so much

Comment: This answer lacks the fclose(fp) call, therefore the code is leaking file handles.

Comment: Hi Erik, I get error "implicit declaration of function is invalid in c99" at `OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is implementation using core security iOS framework. 
Key should be converted to pkcs12 format. 
Algorythm name is "***kSecKeyAlgorithmRSASignatureMessagePKCS1v15SHA1***"

```
- (NSString *)getStringSHA1RSASignature:(NSString *)str
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]
                      pathForResource:@"rsaPrivate.pfx" ofType:@"pkcs12"];
    NSData *p12data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

    NSMutableDictionary * options = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [options setObject:@" your password " forKey:(id)kSecImportExportPassphrase];
    CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);

    OSStatus securityError = SecPKCS12Import((CFDataRef)p12data, (CFDictionaryRef)options, &items);

    CFDictionaryRef identityDict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);
    SecIdentityRef identityApp =
    (SecIdentityRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(identityDict,
                                         kSecImportItemIdentity);
    assert(securityError == noErr);
    SecKeyRef privateKeyRef;
    SecIdentityCopyPrivateKey(identityApp, &privateKeyRef);

    /// have a key
    NSData *input = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    CFErrorRef error = nil;

    ///////////////////////////////// "SHA1withRSA" java
    CFDataRef signature = SecKeyCreateSignature(privateKeyRef, kSecKeyAlgorithmRSASignatureMessagePKCS1v15SHA1, (CFDataRef)input, &error);
    NSAssert(signature != nil, @"");

    NSString *result = [(__bridge NSData *)signature base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    CFRelease(signature);
    NSAssert(result != nil, @"");
    NSLog(@"generated signature: %@", result);

    return result;
}
```